# Cannot POST / express and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

When i try to post this

```
"_id" : "QQCEyALuMpisEcPb2",
"title" : "hola3",
"listId" : "ZSHvg4gEcKr7y424A",
"boardId" : "fnnkpFjRPhdzMFkrJ",
"archived" : false,
"userId" : "yyJWGn2FZ2AwzHsxT"
```

With this Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CardSchema = new Schema({
_id : String,
tittle : String,
listId : String,
boardId : String,
archived :Boolean,
userId : String )};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Card', CardSchema);
```

I cant, it shows me Cannot POST / and i dont know why i tried to insert this json manually in the database and it worked but when i try using this it gives me an error

```
router.route('/cards')
.post(function(req, res) {
    var card = new Card();
    card._id = req.body._id; 
    card.tittle = req.body.tittle;
    card.listId = req.body.listId;
    card.boardId = req.body.boardId;
    card.archived = req.body.archived;
    card.userId = req.body.userId;

    card.save(function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Card created!'})
    });
});
```

I m using REST Console to try this.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: this is router issue, your router is not being registered

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT My bad, doesnt show me an error, just dont let me insert the json and show me cannot POST /

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT   I solved myself, i was rrunning the app in a bad way, the code was ok, ty

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself, i was rrunning the app in a bad way, the code was ok, ty